# Static Utility Class in spring 3 application

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Is it a violation if I go ahead with utility methods as static rather than depending on DI of spring?

I just have to maintain a hashmap like below:

```
private static Map<String,JMSMessage> messageMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String,JMSMessage>());
```

messageMap can be accessed by multiple threads. I have utility methods to play around messageMap. I made my class as final and declared all utility methods as static. Is it a violation according to spring IoC?

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that, even though it is possible and will work correctly in Spring IOC, it is a violation of the principals of inversion-of-control.

It would be better to use a singleton bean that is managed by your IOC than use a static field, like this

```
  @Component
  @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
  public class SimpleMessageManager implements MessageManager {
      private Map messageMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());  

      @Override
      void addMessage(...) { ... }

      @Override
      void getMessage(...) { ... }

  }
```

You could then inject your MessageManager like this:

```
  public class SomeBean {
      @Resource
      MessageManager messageManager;
  }
```

There are many reasons why sticking to the IOC approach is better:

1. You may need more than one instance in future.
2. You can mock out the MessageManager interface in unit tests.
3. (Related to 2) If you use a static fields, you cannot be sure of the state of the messageMap during testing. This becomes even more complicated if you start running your tests in parallel (a standard option in Maven)

*As an aside, I would recommend that you not use Collections.synchronizedMap. Have you considered using ConcurrentHashMap instead?*

Comment: Thanks for the details.@Resource not working in Jboss 5.1. Is there any other method to refer components marked as @Component. I should be able to access it from a normal java class whose instance is created using new

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a violation against spring because the variable is `static`. `Static` variables are only accessible through class name. Spring IoC is useful when you want to **remove dependency** from the **implementation**, so that it can change later on without affecting anything else. In case of `static` variables and methods you have no choice but to **access them through their class name**.

And remember static variables and methods **cannot** be overriden.

Comment: "Static variables are only accessible through class name" - not true, you can access them fine through instance references, even if that's bad style.